# Single Query to retrive records from more than one repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Can Please sugget Best /Efficient way to perform CRUD Opration in MVC application.
I am using Entity Framework in my project for Database access.

ex: EDMX: SupportContext ;

1. Here i performed the CRUD Operation using SupportContext [.edmx}. which processed more quickly than repository. and also i can retrive data's from more than one context object[table's] in a LinQ query.

ex:

```
using (SupportContext support =new SupportContext())
{
var=(from t1 in support.table1
     from t2 in support.table 2
     where t1.id==t2.id
     select t1).ToList();
}
```

1. I have used Generic Repository Pattern for instead of direct access with EDMx. it act layer  between my code logic and EDMX file. find the generic example.

code:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);      
    void Add(T entity);              
    void SaveChanges();
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ObjectContext _context;
    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
    public GenericRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate);
    }                 

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }        

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }             
}
```

Here i have used this repository for CRUD opration as:

```
var dat1=new GenericRepository<Table1>(new SupportContext());
var dat2=new GenericRepository<Table2>(new SupportContext());
```

Here i want to retrieve the records in both dat1,dat2 repository while it Id filed is equal. But I can't able to retrieve in combine way. but do it in single way.

```
var=dat1.Find(t=>t.id==3).toList();
```

Can you please suggest how to retrieve data 's  from combined repository AND also suggest which method is best way to Access data ?

Comment: The key is not have a context instance per repo, but one context shared by all repositories in one unit of work.